# Sorting a table breaks the TableRowListener?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, listeners

I have a sortable default table model with ListSelectionListener that listens for a doubleclick and then opens a details view of a particular column. This works fine, however, when I sort a column the listener no longer functions.

```
JTable foosTable = new JTable(model);
TableRowSorter<TableModel> fooSorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
foosTable.setRowSorter(fooSorter);
ListSelectionModel listMod = foosTable.getSelectionModel();
listMod.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
ListSelectionListener barListener = new ListSelectionListener(foosTable);
listMod.addListSelectionListener(barListener);
```

Comment: can you show some code please? thanks.

Comment: I've never heard of a TableRowListener.

Comment: @camickr. it seems to be in the package org.smir.util.table http://andi-smirre.ath.cx/javadoc/org.smir.util.table/org/smir/util/table/TableRowListener.html Never used it myself.

Comment: A ListSelectionListener doesn't listen for a double click, it just selects a row. Please ask a proper question. And since twice you haven't been able to ask a question with all the required information needed to solve your problem you really need to post a SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem so we don't have to keep guessing what you are actually asking. We don't have time to guess what you actually mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used TableRowListener which seems to only have an `itemChanged` event. I usually stick to standard swing. Add a mouse listener to the table, grab the location of a click event and then handle it.

```
 jTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
     public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
         Point p = new Point(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
         int col = jTable.columnAtPoint(p);
         int row = jTable.rowAtPoint(p);
         if (evt.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
         {
            if (evt.getClickCount() >= 2)
            {
               ...
               ...
            }
        });
```

**Edit**
Setup a [TableRowSorter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html):

```
  TableRowSorter<YourJTableModel> sorter =
        new TableRowSorter<YourJTableModel>(yourJTableModel);
   jTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

Because you are changing the row order, you will need to use [convertColumnIndexToModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel%28int%29)
to get the correct model data for the view.

For more complex sorting/filtering needs you may want to try [glazed lists](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/).

Comment: This fixed my issue, what I had was a class that implemented ListSelectionListener and inherited MouseAdapter.